# Does LeakyRelu have an tensorflow.js implementation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have a Yolo NN, created and trained in Keras (using a LeakyRelu activation function). I converted this model into tensorflow.js using the tensorflowjs converter with the arguments:

`-- input_format keras  --output_format tfjs_graph_model`

The model appeared to convert successfully, but when I load it into JavaScript

`const model = await loadGraphModel("http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json");`

I get an error stating 'Unhandled Rejection (Error): Activation leakyrelu has not been implemented for the WebGL backend.'

I have tried both CPU and WebGL backends and it has not worked. From what I have read so far, the only option is to retrain the model with a different activation function, obviously this is less than ideal.

What is the cause of this error, and if it is that leakyRelu is not implemented for WebGL, what exactly does this mean and is there a way of fixing this without having to retrain the entirety of my model with a different activation function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **TFJS**? I just checked on *3.9.0* and `LeakyReLU` is implemented for `CPU`, `WASM` and `WebGL` backends and not implemented for `WebGPU`. It's also documented at https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.leakyReLU